# Connecting to Neo4j with Javascript (without drivers)

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am trying to connect to my Neo4j database using Javascript without drivers. I am getting a 401 Auth Required error. Here's my js file:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = 'localhost';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);

  var r = require("request");
  var txUrl = "https://hobby-faabenangmiagbkeeiembdbl.dbs.graphenedb.com:24780/db/data/transaction/commit";

  function cypher(query,params,cb) {
  r.post({uri:txUrl,
          json:{statements:[{statement:query,parameters:params}]}},
         function(err,res) {
           cb(err,res.body)
         });
  }

  var query = "MATCH (tom {name: 'Tom Hanks'}) RETURN tom"
  var params = {limit: 10}

  var cb = function(err,data) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
   };

  cypher(query,params,cb);
});
```

Where can I pass in my credentials? I was looking at this but they have no examples of passing in credentials and I was unable to find how to do it without using drivers: https://neo4j.com/developer/the-example-project-4/#_neo4j_for_javascript_developers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Authenticate by sending a username and a password to Neo4j using HTTP
>   Basic Auth. Requests should include an Authorization header, with a
>   value of Basic , where "payload" is a base64 encoded string
>   of "username:password".
>
> https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/authentication/#http-api-authenticate-to-access-the-server

```
function cypher(query, params, cb) {
    r.post({
            uri: txUrl,
            auth: {
                'user': 'user',
                'pass': 'password'
            },
            json: {
                statements: [{
                    statement: query,
                    parameters: params
                }]
            }
        },
        function(err, res) {
            cb(err, res.body)
        });
}
```

https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication

Comment: @DavidPham What should I do when someone answers my question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Gave you the check mark :^) Upvotes aren't recorded for new people like me. Thanks again!